# Longlistselector dynamically update not binded items

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have a longlistselector which is binded to my class. In item template I've got textblock, that is not binded to any field in class.
Is there any way to iterate on list and fill that textblock with data?
Something like this:

```
foreach (var item in myList)
        {
            item.textblock = SomeMethod(item.field);
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you just bind it to some property?

Comment: because I need to update it in metod of another object

Comment: So? If you have the list, then you have access to its items and you can set their properties. (I'm trying to find other solutions, because what you want is rather tricky. Unless it's really necessary, you should prefer some other way of doing it.)

Comment: Method cannot be binded, because the data is filled only when e.g. user clicks the button. Then all items on list will be updated.
If button is not clicked, then all items will be empty.

Comment: Is that method yours? Can you change its code? You can definitely fill in the properties on click and leave them empty before that. Maybe you should share some of your code. It will help me and the others understand what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" Margin="0,0,-12,0">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyTitle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Where *PropertyTitle* is the name of your property

Comment: If your viewmodel, which implements INotifyPropertyChanged, changes the model property, the View should update for the record that changed.